# How to get the "query string" from a QUrl?

Tags: http, qt, qurl

I have a QUrl and I need to extract the path+file+params. Basically everything but the hostname - what would be requested via HTTP.

I looked through the Qt 4.6 docs but I couldn't find anything that looked like it would do this.

What method(s) would I call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can clear the scheme with `setScheme`. After that the url will be relative so it shouldn't return the hostname anymore when converting it to a string.

```
QUrl someUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar?spam=eggs");
someUrl.setScheme("");
someUrl.toString();
```

Or, you can give the `toString()` method some extra parameters:

```
QUrl someUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar?spam=eggs");
someUrl.toString(QUrl::RemoveScheme);
```

Comment: Thanks. That'll work just great. One more question - when I call toString, does it return a URL-encoded string?

Comment: For an urlencoded `toString` you can use `toEncoded`.
Docs: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qurl.html#toEncoded